LTspice: Change fontsize on all components in circuit
The circuit in the attached screenshot already looks too crowded, and I'd like to add even more voltage nodes.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to decrease the fontsize of the nodes and the texts of the circuit symbols.
Or the number of decimal places on the nodes.

You can change the font from the Tools menu, under Control Panel/Drafting Options.
To change the number of decimal places right click the voltage label and in the dialog that pops up at the bottom you will see an edit field with a $. Change it to round($*1000)/1000. That will round it to three places, you can change the number of places by changing the 1000s to some other multiple of 10, for instance round($*100)/100 will round to two places. You have to do each label separately.
